# antlr error "no viable alternative at input"

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm following the example given here- 
https://datapsyche.wordpress.com/2014/10/23/back-to-learning-grammar-with-antlr/

which basically has following grammar-

```
grammar Simpleql;

statement : expr command* ; 
expr : expr ('AND' | 'OR' | 'NOT') expr # expopexp
 | expr expr # expexp
 | predicate # predicexpr
 | text # textexpr
 | '(' expr ')' # exprgroup
 ;
predicate : text ('=' | '!=' | '>=' | '<=' | '>' | '<') text ; 
command : '| show' text* # showcmd
 | '| show' text (',' text)* # showcsv
 ;
text : NUMBER # numbertxt 
 | QTEXT # quotedtxt
 | UQTEXT # unquotedtxt
 ;

AND : 'AND' ;
OR : 'OR' ;
NOT : 'NOT' ;
EQUALS : '=' ;
NOTEQUALS : '!=' ;
GREQUALS : '>=' ;
LSEQUALS : '<=' ;
GREATERTHAN : '>' ;
LESSTHAN : '<' ;

NUMBER : DIGIT+
 | DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+
 | '.' DIGIT+
 ;
QTEXT : '"' (ESC|.)*? '"' ;
UQTEXT : ~[ ()=,<>!\r\n]+ ;

fragment
DIGIT : [0-9] ;
fragment
ESC : '\\"' | '\\\\' ; 

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When I pass input like this-

```
Abishek AND (country=India OR city=NY) LOGIN 404 | show name city
```

I get error- `line 1:65 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'`

I went through a couple of SO posts related to the error but can't seem to be able to figure out what is wrong with the grammar.

Comment: If you dump the token stream, do you wind up having `UQTEXT` tokens with the content you expect? The other tokens as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running your example but was thrown a number of errors in antlrworks 2. However i was able to run it without any errors in the test rig getting the following output:

```
(statement (expr (expr (expr (text Abishek)) AND (expr ( (expr (expr (predicate (text country) = (text India))) OR (expr (predicate (text city) = (text NY)))) ))) (expr (expr (text LOGIN)) (expr (text 404)))) (command | show (text name) (text city)))
```

And the same output of the tree shown on the website.

My opinion on what's wrong may be your actual input, iv had problems in the past with ANTLR reading text from a file if the file was not encoded to be ascii/ansi/utf-8 or whatever works for the os you are using. I encountered this when i saved a file on linux from a linux text editor and tried to run it on windows with the same generated parser. So my recommendation is try re-saving your text input - 'Abishek AND (country=India OR city=NY) LOGIN 404 | show name city' and make sure the encoding is different each time incase this is the cause.

Note you can also specify the encoding like this or similar ways :

```
CharStream charStream = new ANTLRInputStream(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Since having an encoding error will cause it to try and parse irrelevant of encoding and result in no matches being found.

Let me know if it works after saving encoded in a few different ways and i'll try and help further. Hope this helps.